# How to clone an object in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm quite new to as3, but the game I'm making requires the use ofclones. How would I make them (I know it involves using the child thing but I don't know how to make them)? I also need to make a function that sets their location to random places on screen, how would I do this? I'm not sure how i would refer to the clone's x and y locations without it moving all 50 of them.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The best way to make clones of anything is to assign AS3 class to the Library item (lets say you named the class **SomeThing**) and then instantiate it with the **new** operator and add to display list with **addChild(...)** method.

```
import SomeThing;

// Lets create a list to keep things.
var things:Vector.<SomeThing> = new Vector.<SomeThing>;

function addThing():SomeThing
{
    // Create.
    var result:SomeThing = new SomeThing;

    // Put it to a list for further reference.
    things.push(result);

    // Add it to display list.
    addChild(result);

    return result;
}

// Create one thing.
// This one will go to (0,0) coordinates.
addThing();

// You can create several things.
for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var aThing:SomeThing = addThing();

    aThing.x = 100 + 200 * Math.random();
    aThing.y = 100 + 100 * Math.random();
}

// Now you can address things via list access.
things[49].x = 50;
things[49].y = 50;
```

Comment: @NealDavis If constructor requires no mandatory arguments the () can be as well omited. It's fine.